# xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

Since I have migrated to null safety I am getting this error.
I have done some research and try the solutions proposed, but none of them are working. Before the null safety, the application was running perfectly fine. I do not see the link between the two.
Please, can you advise?

Since yesterday, I have done a lot of test.

1/ I have gone back to my code, before the migration to null safety. (I am getting the same error). So then,
2/ I have removed Xcode and re-installed it.
3/ I have installed VS to see if I am getting the same error.
4/ I have also created a new project

But I am still getting the same error

Below, I have added the podfile.

Many thanks.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           1820,8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A7827DDA-D57C-4C7D-AF29-D287404A098F, OS:15.2, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:655072F5-B78B-417A-A39A-E2EF5F367D1A, OS:15.2, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0089D625-2CF5-4037-B54A-B302EBAC428A, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9D539B42-3FA0-40D0-B057-50E22BC1AAE1, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E59D0A6F-171D-440F-BB77-28FB1A7E28B4, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E063D8D1-3B73-4E0A-BFD5-17F85D82387A, OS:15.2, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EFA25E9A-ED6D-45C8-AC6C-E6F170897C35, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B5CE0C5D-F2CB-41DA-BAD4-7E89B1B6F77D, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9217628D-E12D-4BFF-9B2C-AB8835B94445, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0BED3881-E61C-424C-A43B-3C9569D0397B, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BB2713D1-33BF-451F-93C8-57ED8894D299, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6E0A1CE0-AB51-4AC4-A584-90C26129193C, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:830FB104-86CB-4779-9EB5-579C3746CA79, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:62CF789F-CE28-44C2-B715-E2BA9F7BD2CD, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8D437B0A-B37D-4BDC-9A45-D78A9CA8A2A8, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:C5939601-18C5-4190-9E3C-05D6CEF673E3, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F4087585-C491-4CA6-96D3-CBB37B42FEBF, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:412775AA-DBD1-459A-B95C-BF3279EE719D, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1F57B67C-C80F-4E38-8F40-518D43ABF13D, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5B2AA7DD-EB1B-42D3-B818-D6C26533E9DD, OS:15.2, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F0FA2173-CC30-4D40-B738-4FD16E29EBC8, OS:15.2, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

PodFile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'

      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
      ]

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you used `flutter clean` ?

Comment: yes. I have done that.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are having the same issue. I have tried all the solutions find on internet.
None of them has worked.
I have decided to create a new project and then to copy one by one my dart files into it.
I have re-imported all my dependencies in pubspec.
Now, it is working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Open the xcworkspace file in Xcode. Open Signin and Capabilities then select "all" then select signing automatically if you have the account added in Xcode and build once from xcode

```dart
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried, but it does not work.

Comment: I am going back to my previous version without null safety. I have spend one full day trying to fix that. My project is not progressing today. So, I will continue and try the null safety later.

Comment: can you add your Podfile here?

Comment: Done. I have added my podfile in my previous message

Comment: platform :ios, '12.0' change it to 12

Comment: I have modified it and I am trying to run the application

Comment: I still have the same error message

Comment: config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0' this is set to 10.. increase it to 12

Comment: Modification done. But I am getting the same error message

Comment: Updated my answer with my podfile. Can you try eith that pls

Comment: I will try and update you asap. thank you

Comment: I have used your podfile and get this. CocoaPods' output:
↳

    [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
    ...d install with arch -x86_64 pod install
    ...                            ^~~
    .

     #  from /Users/gb/Documents/my_gtd_20210820/ios/Podfile:42
     #  -------------------------------------------
     #  end
     >  ow try pod install with arch -x86_64 pod install
     #  
     #  -------------------------------------------

Comment: I am getting this now [!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies. and [!] Could not automatically select an Xcode workspace. Specify one in your Podfile like so: workspace 'path/to/Workspace.xcworkspace'

Comment: Run pod install from terminal in your ios directory

Comment: [!] Could not automatically select an Xcode workspace. Specify one in your Podfile like so:

    workspace 'path/to/Workspace.xcworkspace'.      //the pod install does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246892/discussion-between-kaushik-chandru-and-laurent-thomas).